# How to use webhook lib of bots business inside our website?

Tags: bots.business

Hello i want to know can I use webhook lib inside my website because when I change user_id in webhook then it show error

```
https://api.bots.business/v1/bots/185720/new-webhook?&command=Bok%24%40%25%23%5E&public_user_token=cad2968320d3a8ef7149fb1c9af582aa&user_id=72992
```

See At The Bottom Of Url.
It have user_id parameter when I change it it show error,so can i use webhook lib in our website to easy my devlopment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bot webhook instead user webhook
In BJS:

```
let webhookUrl = Libs.Webhooks.getUrlFor({
  // this command will be runned on webhook
  command: "/onWebhook"
})
```

Then you can pass user_id in request (web page):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: webhookUrl,
  data: { user_id: YOUR_USER_ID },
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

on webhook command (BJS) - run command for user

```
Bot.run({ command: '/your_user_command', user_id: content.user_id })
```

Comment: Please note! It is possible to change user_id in your page. It can be unesecure